# Getting 'Forbidden' on clicking 'Enqueue now'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq-cron

Getting 'Forbidden' on clicking 'Enqueue now' in staging and production environment.

Using 'rails', '5.1.6', sidekiq-cron (1.0.4) which uses fugit (~> 1.1) and sidekiq (>= 4.2.1)

I can see from [sidekiq-cron issue 60](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron/issues/60/) and [sidekiq-cron issue 61](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron/issues/61) that issue got resolved a long back but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq::Web uses Rack::Protection to protect application against typical web attacks (e.g CSRF, XSS, etc). Rack::Protection would invalidate session and raise 'Forbidden' error if it finds that request doesn't satisfy security requirements. One of the possible situations is having application working behind a reverse proxy and not passing important headers to it (X-Forwarded-For,X-Forwarded-Proto).

Well after spending enough time figuring out the issue. This is what helped me.

Nginx configuration:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;  
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;  
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
proxy_redirect off;  
proxy_http_version 1.1;  
proxy_set_header Connection '';  
proxy_pass http://app;
#proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
#proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
#proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```

Other solutions, which did not work for me but worked for others:

[Sidekiq monitoring](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#forbidden)

[Sidekiq issue 2487](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2487)

[Rack protection and nginx](https://www.sourcediver.org/blog/2015/07/01/rack-protection-and-nginx/)

[Sidekiq issue 2560](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2560)